# Can we display around 100000 rows using React-Table by consuming Json data via API?

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement to consume huge volume of data ( like more than 100000 rows) by calling API end point and Data format is JSON and display them in react page. I am developing the logic using React-Table, but would like to hear experts opinion to know whether this is possible in reactjs? Is React-Table the right option in reactjs? Will there be performance issues?

Comment: Why display them all at once? Paging?

Comment: He could display all items for a variety of reasons, all of which are not subject of the answer

Answer (score 8):

Yes this is surely possible but involves the usage of virtual views like [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized)
The problem with 100k rows is that **first render takes a lot of time**, scroll could be tedious and **every re-render takes a significant amount of time too**.
With **virtual views data** is rendered only in active viewport and element are added/removed upon scroll **reducing the rendering/reconciliation payload**.

Comment: ok. Thanks Mose. I will explore this option. Right now I have used react-table and pagination and tested with 2000 rows , look good. will try to explore with higher volumes using react-table too and post the results.

Comment: If you encounter some sort of bottleneck, this article is really useful: https://www.sumologic.com/blog/code/react-table-alternatives/